# importing google play services without using the eclipse project

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play-services

I want to use Notification service in my app. I am using one of the cross-platform SDK and wants to make a plugin, which can be used in implementing notifications functionality.

The SDK do not support eclipse projects to be included directly. I can add either jar files or java files.Adding a res folder is supported too.

The problem is I can't seem to find classes from the google_play_services eclipse library project. They are not in the jar files. Is there any way I can create a jar file including just the required files or is there any source for the services, which I can compile on my own??

PS: The package which I am unable to find is - com.google.android.gms.common

Thanks

Comment: I don't think information about the cross-platform SDK I am using is required, since this is a generic question. But in case you're wondering it's marmalade SDK. (Please do not tag it with marmalade).

Comment: I can see that package in the play services jar file so perhaps this is marmalade specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is  the jar file which you could import http://www.mediafire.com/download/5w6x1u2xmpgq8fy/google-play-services.jar

files

`com.google.android.gms.internal.x.class
com.google.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException.class
com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException.class
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.by.class
com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableNotifiedException.class
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.aj.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bu.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.d.class
com.google.android.gms.panorama.PanoramaClient.class
com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.be.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.am.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bv.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ak.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bo.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.v.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bt.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bz.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cl.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.an.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ax.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.as.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ce.class
com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferRef.class
com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolderCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.common.data.EntityBuffer.class
com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBuffer.class
com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder.class
com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferIterator.class
com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bd.class
com.google.android.gms.common.data.Freezable.class
com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cf.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bx.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ch.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.u.class
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.class
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.class
com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.class
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException.class
com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.class
com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.r.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bj.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.q.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.j.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.s.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.az.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.br.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cj.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.aa.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.n.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.c.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.co.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.aq.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ah.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bw.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.w.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ck.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bf.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ac.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.model.apps.ApplicationBuffer.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.model.moments.ItemScope.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.model.moments.Moment.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.model.moments.MomentBuffer.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.PersonBuffer.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.GooglePlusUtil.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bc.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bs.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bn.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ci.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ay.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ca.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bi.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.at.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cg.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ba.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.af.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bl.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cb.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bb.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ad.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cn.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bg.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cc.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bq.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ao.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ai.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.l.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.y.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ag.class
com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusShare.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileProvider.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPositionCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlay.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptionsCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlay.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.VisibleRegionCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.RuntimeRemoteException.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.UrlTileProvider.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlayOptionsCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptionsCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBoundsCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.GroundOverlayOptions.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.VisibleRegion.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptionsCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptionsCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.h.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.av.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.b.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bm.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.IPolylineDelegate.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ae.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.au.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.z.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Tile.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptionsCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptionsCreator.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ILocationSourceDelegate.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.a.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bk.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.m.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.bp.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.o.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IProjectionDelegate.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cd.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.al.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IUiSettingsDelegate.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.p.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ar.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.cm.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ICameraUpdateFactoryDelegate.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ab.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.k.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.g.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.t.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.class
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.f.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.ap.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.aw.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.i.class
com.google.android.gms.internal.e.class
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.LifecycleDelegate.class`

Comment: Thanks, but is it officially supported? I just wanted to implement push notifications.